# What is the best way to remove elements on screen in terms of performance, speed, best-practice etc.?

Tags: iphone, ios, performance, alpha

On a number of elements within a feature of my application, they are coming in and out of view (possibly a couple of times in a second)

I would like some advice on whether it is better to remove the view from its superview or whether it is fine by just adjusting the alpha value (either 0.0 or 1.0) each time I want it removed/added.

Note: 'Better' can refer to performance, speed, best-practice etc.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: There is one major difference between removeFromSuperview and setting alpha to 0 if there is no other reference to the view: dealloc.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are not using the subview anymore, I'd suggest you remove it completely. If it has to reappear, setting the alpha value might be better.